# Capture between round brackets and square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a text similar to this:

```
[text]
(more text)
(text...)
[text!]
(last text)
```

I need to match the text between () and [].
The output should be something like this:

```
[
  "text",
  "more text",
  "text...",
  "text!",
  "last text"
]
```

I already tried `/[\[\(](.*?)[\]\)]/` but it didn't work in PHP.
Here is the code if you need it:

```
 preg_match_all('/[\[\(](.*?)[\]\)]/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
 var_dump($matches);
```

How do I achieve this using regex in PHP?

Thanks in advance, 
Skayo

Comment: But this regex will also match `[abcd)`

Comment: Yes, I know. But in this case it's not bad.

Comment: If you don't have any text outside the brackets: [`[^][)(]+`](https://regex101.com/r/xqKuPM/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that code works like a charm. You just need to add a line to filter out the matched sections:

```
$texts = array_column($matches, 1);
```

See https://3v4l.org/uCHIB for a working example.

Comment: You're right, it works... 
I had another problem wich has nothing to do with the regex.
Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a regex based on a [**branch reset**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html') feature:

```
$re = '/(?|\[([^]]*)]|\(([^)]*)\))/';
$str = '[text]
(more text)
(text...)
[text!]
(last text)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/JwphvX)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CjR0h/1)

- `(?|` - start of the branch reset
- `\[` - a `[`
- `([^]]*)` - any 0+ chars other than `]`
- `]`  - a literal `]`
- `|` - or
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `([^)]*)` - any 0+ chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`
- `)` - end of the branch reset group.